# How to select usage suggestion hint

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I type the name of a class without specifying the full namespace and the class is not made available by the using statements, Visual Studio guesses which class I mean and shows the fully namespaced class name in a hint.

For example:

[image: example]

If I click it it adds the necessary using statement.

How can I select that hint using the keyboard?

Comment: what version of vs? Anyway you may want to place the cursor on the class name and try alt+shift+F10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that this actually a ReSharper feature (not something that is built into Visual Studio) and I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it.